# How to stop multiple browsers running on the same machine from accessing a certain web page?

Tags: php, http, session, cookies, web

My application requires that only one(first) among multiple browsers running on one PC is able to access a certain web page and the requests from other browsers is blocked/not serviced ? Is there anyway to do this using php ? Is there a way to do it even if I don't restrict myself to php ? I have looked into sessions and cookies but there doesn't seem to be a method to share cookies between browsers(sharing sessions is entirely out of question, I understand). Since private IPs are not known to the server, I can't develop a method to use those either, I'm stuck, any help will be appreciated.
PS: I'm an intern at a firm, and I wasn't told the exact scenario this feature is required for, but this is what is needed to be done. I suggested using client authorization(login id, password) for it, but that suggestion was rejected, I'm stuck ! 
EDIT: I only create a session if a client with the same IP (flags for ip stored in a DB) is not surfing the page., otherwise if same ip is already in session, they are thrown out... It isn't really an exercise, they want a working solution !. I get the IP by $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] - It blocks the global IPs which I don't really want.
EDIT 2 : How about using a java applet or flash cookies(in a roundabout way somehow) to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

That can't be done, at least not in a fool proof way. The different browsers could be using different proxies, so filtering by IP won't be enough even if you could do it. Ask why this needs to be done, and then when you know what actually is required, look for a way to do it.

Comment: No way to get the private IP anyway right ? is it possible to get it from ...say a java applet ?, is it possible to access flash cookies from php ? because they are shared between browsers I think. Some form of user authentication would solve this, but what's stopping a person from making multiple accounts then ?

Comment: It really sounds like that your actual problem is poor communications. You are asked to deliver a solution "X", when what they actually want is you to solve problem "Y". If you don't know what the problem is that this - forgive me for saying so - crude hack is supposed to solve, how can you really be able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is an exercise, It seems you're indeed asked to do the impossible. However, Assuming they want the general solution that will work in most cases, Take a look at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - This will return the client's IP **or** his proxy server, In case of a proxy server, you can also use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` to get the client IP.

**word of caution** : `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` - can be spoofed, so it's not to be trusted, However 99% of the users have no idea what's a proxy or how to fake this setting.

It's not a 100% fool-proof solution, But for that you'll really want a login mechanism, There's no other solution that comes to mind.

Comment: already did that, I only create a session if a client with the same IP (flags for ip stored in a DB) is not surfing the page., otherwise if same ip is already in session, they are thrown out... It isn't really an exercise, they want a working solution !

Comment: So yea, I don't know of any other solution :)

Comment: you should also edit your answer to let people know what you've done, You didn't specify you've done this part, you clearly mentioned you can't use IP's

Comment: ok, will do, thanks for the tip, my first ever post here ! though I have been referring to SO forver !

Comment: Welcome! we don't bite :)